# Hyperledger Fabric - PKCS8 private keys from identity javascript Object

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects, hyperledger-fabric, pem, pkcs#8

I am building a project using hyperledger fabric running on a local [IBM MicroFab blockchain network](https://github.com/IBM-Blockchain/microfab). I have been experiencing issues in regard to identity and retrieving connection information from the MicroFab api (/ak/api/v1/components). Formatting the private key and certificate properly seems to be the fix to me but I am dumbfounded on a solution. Microfab unfortunately does not have any or much documentation.

error:

```
malformed plain PKCS8 private key(code:001)
```

The returned json object from the api contains the following information (long key text omitted):

```
[
  {
    id: 'p0000admin',
    display_name: 'p0000 Admin',
    type: 'identity',
    cert: 'LS0tLS.....0tLS0tCg==',
    private_key: 'LS0t....FIEtFWS0tLS0tCg==',
    ca: 'LS0tL....LS0tCg==',
    msp_id: 'p0000MSP',
    wallet: 'p0000',
    hide: false
  }
]
```

I am currently taking the first and only json within this object and pulling out the Private key and Certificate strings, which is then concatenated within the following identity object which is my attempt to convert the raw keys to PEM:

```
const identityLabel = `p${userid} Admin`;
  const identity = {
    credentials: {
        certificate: `-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\n${rawcertificate}\n-----END CERTIFICATE-----\n`,
        privateKey: `-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\n${rawprivatekey}\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n`,
    },
    mspId: `p${userid}MSP`,
    type: 'X.509',
};
```

my console error is as follows:

```
error: [crypto_ecdsa_aes]: createKeyFromRaw - Failed to parse key from PEM:  message=malformed plain PKCS8 private key(code:001), stack=Error: malformed plain PKCS8 private key(code:001)
    at Object.parsePlainPrivatePKCS8Hex (/home/tylr/Documents/IEEE/next-energychain/node_modules/jsrsasign/lib/jsrsasign.js:238:5296)
    at Object.getKeyFromPlainPrivatePKCS8Hex (/home/tylr/Documents/IEEE/next-energychain/node_modules/jsrsasign/lib/jsrsasign.js:238:6073)
    at Object.getKeyFromPlainPrivatePKCS8PEM (/home/tylr/Documents/IEEE/next-energychain/node_modules/jsrsasign/lib/jsrsasign.js:238:5975)
    at KEYUTIL.getKey (/home/tylr/Documents/IEEE/next-energychain/node_modules/jsrsasign/lib/jsrsasign.js:238:11905)
    at CryptoSuite_ECDSA_AES.createKeyFromRaw (/home/tylr/Documents/IEEE/next-energychain/node_modules/fabric-common/lib/impl/CryptoSuite_ECDSA_AES.js:132:18)
    at X509Provider.getUserContext (/home/tylr/Documents/IEEE/next-energychain/node_modules/fabric-network/lib/impl/wallet/x509identity.js:61:46)
    at Gateway.connect (/home/tylr/Documents/IEEE/next-energychain/node_modules/fabric-network/lib/gateway.js:257:41)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async evaluateTransaction (webpack-internal:///(api)/./hyperledger/api-EvaluateTransaction.js:82:9)
API failed to fetch: Error: Failed to parse key from PEM: Error: malformed plain PKCS8 private key(code:001)
    at CryptoSuite_ECDSA_AES.createKeyFromRaw (/home/tylr/Documents/IEEE/next-energychain/node_modules/fabric-common/lib/impl/CryptoSuite_ECDSA_AES.js:135:10)
    at X509Provider.getUserContext (/home/tylr/Documents/IEEE/next-energychain/node_modules/fabric-network/lib/impl/wallet/x509identity.js:61:46)
    at Gateway.connect (/home/tylr/Documents/IEEE/next-energychain/node_modules/fabric-network/lib/gateway.js:257:41)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async evaluateTransaction (webpack-internal:///(api)/./hyperledger/api-EvaluateTransaction.js:82:9)
```

Project code below:

```
const microfabjson = await fetch('http://console.127.0.0.1.nip.io:8081/ak/api/v1/components', { 
    headers: {
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'Path': '/',
    }
  })
    .then(response => response.json())
  
  // console.log(res)
  console.log(microfabjson)


  const connectionProfile = microfabjson.filter(obj=> obj.type == "gateway" && obj.wallet == `p${userid}`)
  const identity_json = microfabjson.filter(obj=> obj.type == "identity" && obj.id == `p${userid}admin`)
  const rawcertificate = identity_json[0].cert
  const rawprivatekey = identity_json[0].private_key
  const mspid = identity_json[0].msp_id

  const identityLabel = `p${userid} Admin`;
  const identity = {
    credentials: {
        certificate: `-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\n${rawcertificate}\n-----END CERTIFICATE-----\n`,
        privateKey: `-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\n${rawprivatekey}\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n`,
    },
    mspId: `p${userid}MSP`,
    type: 'X.509',
};
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the certificates and private keys returned by the Microfab REST API are the complete PEM-encoded content, additionally base64-endoded. So if you just base64 decode the raw `cert` and `private_key` fields then you have the complete PEM with no need to add the BEGIN and END elements.

For example, on my system:

```
const http = require('http');

http.get('http://console.127.0.0.1.nip.io:8080/ak/api/v1/components', response => {
    const chunks = [];
    response.on('data', chunk => chunks.push(chunk));
    response.on('end', () => {
        const data = chunks.join('');
        JSON.parse(data)
            .filter(entry => entry.type === 'identity')
            .forEach(entry => {
                const certificate = Buffer.from(entry.cert, 'base64').toString();
                const privateKey = Buffer.from(entry.private_key, 'base64').toString();
                const credentials = { certificate, privateKey };
                console.log(`${entry.id}:`, credentials);
            });
    });
}).on('error', console.error);
```

Gives this output (with all but one identity removed to keep it concise!):

```
ordereradmin: {
  certificate: '-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\n' +
    'MIIB1TCCAXugAwIBAgIRAICUAsKQVM5DKllfmC7us6swCgYIKoZIzj0EAwIwFTET\n' +
    'MBEGA1UEAxMKT3JkZXJlciBDQTAeFw0yMjA5MjEwOTE2MTBaFw0zMjA5MTgwOTE2\n' +
    'MTBaMCgxDjAMBgNVBAsTBWFkbWluMRYwFAYDVQQDEw1PcmRlcmVyIEFkbWluMFkw\n' +
    'EwYHKoZIzj0CAQYIKoZIzj0DAQcDQgAErYZwEFjbqYvkpaCok27K1GK9jsYAzcR3\n' +
    'vwIo0YwMN6/G/na/tJiDYxI7vSwhVrWhmUjXCNQDUQcesrrNEFWFhqOBmDCBlTAO\n' +
    'BgNVHQ8BAf8EBAMCBaAwHQYDVR0lBBYwFAYIKwYBBQUHAwIGCCsGAQUFBwMBMAwG\n' +
    'A1UdEwEB/wQCMAAwKQYDVR0OBCIEIHg+NWsNrjwB99CSjRhY/mJUeIJ2uFl3LpXp\n' +
    'pworjoY5MCsGA1UdIwQkMCKAINKbV22Xkrv6Ok0W8GfZqqpr6QBLHjTCAg9WTAJm\n' +
    'tRAfMAoGCCqGSM49BAMCA0gAMEUCIDKWitYF0Pg0YdFOOyXhmYGXSpmYsKaQHbFb\n' +
    'hDLx7ktYAiEAuhrXUaXvddGAMotkpRfTEbXCvG1gDlg74dNt2Qg/qMk=\n' +
    '-----END CERTIFICATE-----\n',
  privateKey: '-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\n' +
    'MIGHAgEAMBMGByqGSM49AgEGCCqGSM49AwEHBG0wawIBAQQgCNjF+ONc9zVWoqzN\n' +
    'V/KlGxzHRXowo/8EVseqj8svTAGhRANCAASthnAQWNupi+SloKiTbsrUYr2OxgDN\n' +
    'xHe/AijRjAw3r8b+dr+0mINjEju9LCFWtaGZSNcI1ANRBx6yus0QVYWG\n' +
    '-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n'
}
```

Comment: Sorry, but I'm not very well versed in this matter. How do I use the returned values from http.get?

Comment: The code above shows the returned values being used. I used http.get to provide a simple example using only built-in Node packages. Use your favourite HTTP package and then parse the results appropriately for your case. The key point is that the cert and private_key fields are base64-encoded, and base64-decoding them gives the complete PEM content, including header and footer